# A Network related error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.5

I faced this error sometimes or sometimes not (sometimes app run properly),but now it is giving me error again and again. 
I am running my application on local host.Following are the error details. 
I am not sure why I am facing this error, I think I am doing something wrong. Due to this error I am stuck at my further working on my project.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

  <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
            <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
            <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
        <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" /><section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" /></sectionGroup></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\mydb.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" /> <!--i have made new version from 2.0.0.0 to 3-->
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" /><!--i have made new version from 2.0.0.0 to 3-->
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
   <!--This prevents the Windows Event Log from frequently logging that HMAC1 is being used (when the other party needs it). <legacyHMACWarning enabled="0" /> When targeting ASP.NET MVC 3, this assemblyBinding makes MVC 1 and 2 references relink
             to MVC 3 so libraries such as DotNetOpenAuth that compile against MVC 1 will work with it.-->
    </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true" />
        <settings>
             <!--This setting causes .NET to check certificate revocation lists (CRL) 
                 before trusting HTTPS certificates.  But this setting tends to not 
                 be allowed in shared hosting environments.--> 
            <servicePointManager checkCertificateRevocationList="true" />
        </settings>
    </system.net><dotNetOpenAuth>
        <messaging>
            <untrustedWebRequest>
                <whitelistHosts>
                     <!--Uncomment to enable communication with localhost (should generally not activate in production!)--> 
                    <add name="localhost" />
                </whitelistHosts>
            </untrustedWebRequest>
        </messaging>
         <!--Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library.--> 
        <!--<reporting enabled="true" />-->
     <!--This is an optional configuration section where aspects of dotnetopenauth can be customized.  For a complete set of configuration options see http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/configuration-options/--> <openid>
        <relyingParty>
                <security requireSsl="false">
                     Uncomment the trustedProviders tag if your relying party should only accept positive assertions from a closed set of OpenID Providers. 
                    <trustedProviders rejectAssertionsFromUntrustedProviders="true">
                        <add endpoint="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud" />
                    </trustedProviders>
                </security>
                <behaviors>
                     <!--The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
                         with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats).--> 
                    <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" />
                </behaviors>
            </relyingParty></openid></dotNetOpenAuth><uri>
         <!--The uri section is necessary to turn on .NET 3.5 support for IDN (international domain names),
             which is necessary for OpenID urls with unicode characters in the domain/host name.
             It is also required to put the Uri class into RFC 3986 escaping mode, which OpenID and OAuth require.--> 
        <idn enabled="All" />
        <iriParsing enabled="true" />
    </uri></configuration>
```

Comment: It appears that your SQL server is not accessible from the server where your application is running. Could be many reasons: the SQL server is down, networking issues, firewalls, ... In all cases you should contact the administrators of this server. It's not your code that's in fault.

Comment: The server appears to be locally hosted. Is this always being run on the same machine?

Comment: Does the identity from the appPool associated to the website have file level permissions on the database file?

Comment: Recheck connection string. And confirm if your able log in to server from Management Studio.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I took code from other machine and on my machine i have made a new project and use existing models, views and controllers. How can i make it run on my local host i.e. IIS ?

Comment: @EM923: can u see whether SQL services are running in your local system? Open services.msc and have a look. Sometimes it happens that local SQL is not accessible because the services are not running or the password has been changed.

Comment: @EM923 It looks like you forgot to take the actual SQL Server database across to the other machine.  The context in your connection string is localhost.

Comment: @JaneS I have .mdf file in my app data folder, i can access db tables as i have entered some records manually. Should i make a new database ? But it will be a daunting task ! Can I do something with existing DB ?

Comment: @EM923 No, you shouldn't have to do that.  Do you consistently fail to connect from within your project?

Comment: @JaneS i have mentioned in my post that sometimes it will work perfectly ! Now it is giving me constant error.

Comment: @Anurag in Administrative tools, in services window exactly which service should i check ? I mean exact name of service ?

Comment: @EM923 Have you been working on the same machine the whole time?  Did it sometimes work on the machine that it now consistently fails on?

Comment: @JaneS yes on just single same machine.

Comment: I know it's a cliché, but have you tried rebooting?  Have you rebooted in between it working and NOT working?  Perhaps the SQL Server Express service is not set to start automatically?  (That is the service name you are looking for)

Comment: @JaneS i have VS 2013 update 4, with built in server. But I am not seeing any " SQL Server Express Service " in my services window. Only i am seeing is a "SQL server VSS writer" in services window.

Comment: @EM923: Can you please look for the service named as SQL server and SQL server agent? See whether it has been configured in your login name..try to see for the password change n stuff.

Comment: @Anurag There is no such service in my services window, whereas there is a driver namely "SQL Server" and "SQL server native client 11.0" in my ODBC Data source administrator drivers window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls.Try to clear log files from following location and restart your sql server :-

C:\Documents and Settings\Your pc-user\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS